# Did Arnold smoke Cannabis at the end of Pumping Iron?

Tags: pumping-iron

**Disclaimer:** This question contains drug references not suitable for younger users<sup>**1**</sup>.

---

I remember watching [***Pumping Iron (1977)***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_Iron) and I was only young when I saw it.

At the end of the film, there was a scene where [**Arnold**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnold_Schwarzenegger) and his colleagues are chilling in a room and celebrating [**Lou Ferrigno**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lou_Ferrigno)'s birthday, during which Arnold lets loose and has a smoke.

Being young, I assumed this was a tobacco cigarette, but later (recently) I heard that it was actually a Marijuana "joint".

**Did Arnold smoke tobacco or marijuana in Pumping Iron?**

---

<sup>**1.**  See [age gate](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1712/11244) for more info on minimum users' age.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's pretty much common knowledge that Arnold was a marijuana user.  Here is a bit about him admitting it was marijuana:

[Arnold's marijuana moment](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/arnolds-marijuana-moment/)